# Where to put returns around callbacks with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

A little background; I work with node.js, and have found that many bugs are avoided by returning **all** callbacks in asynchronous code. For example:

```
function useMyAsyncFunc(stuff, c, callback)
    myAsyncFunc(stuff.a, stuff.b, c, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        // Long body of code in here.

        return callback(null, data);
    });
}
```

My question is, would it be better to do the above, considering that the chain of callbacks could be quite large, or would

```
function useMyAsyncFunc(stuff, c, callback)
    myAsyncFunc(stuff.a, stuff.b, c, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
           callback(error);
           return;
        }

        // Long body of code in here.

        callback(null, data);
        return;
    });
}
```

be more efficient?

Put more explicitly, does node benefit from the latter, where it is told to ignore the return value of the callback function?

Comment: I think it makes no difference.

Comment: If it's asynchronous, the `return` value is irrelevant. Just remove them.

Comment: @user1689607 NO! The return is absolutely relevant. If you don't return the first callback here, you call it twice.

Comment: `return callback(...);` is best practice.

Comment: @Pointy Are you sure? The latter explicitly tells V8 to ignore any possible return value of the callback, whereas I'm not sure if the former requires much overhead in working it out on its own.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Sorry, use an `else` and forget the `return`. Or ditch the `if` altogether, and just do `callback(error, data)`. If there's no `error`, then obviously it won't be passed.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I disagree. It begs the question of *"What is the function doing with the return value"*. Why explicitly return some value that you know will be ignored? IMO, it adds confusion to the code.

Comment: @user1689607 This is not so good, because you end up with deeper nesting. It is usually better (my example is not great because this is clearer with a larger body in that anonymous function) to return early if possible to avoid nesting.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: And that's a totally valid point. But this is the trouble with the question. There is no "right" answer. It depends on the situation as well as personal coding standards.

Comment: @user1689607 It's not the question though. The question is rather, does one style of returning have more of an overhead than the other, not if I should be returning at all.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I see. I wasn't clear on what was meant. Your update helps. JavaScript is always pass by value, but the larger data structures are implemented as ReferenceTypes, so passing is very light weight. I don't believe that you'll ever pass/return more than 64 bits of data, and if the caller makes no use of the return value, the implementation may even optimize that away. So *if* there's any benefit, it is minuscule.

Comment: @user1689607 This is what I'm hoping. I prefer the former, because it's clearer to me that a callback next to a return is an exit point from the function. It also evokes the notion of tails calls, which I like even if tail call optimisations aren't a big thing in JS (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I likewise agree that in general the "return callback()" does no harm nor does it significantly affect performance versus "callback(); return;".  I decided to test that along with testing "process.nextTick(... cb ...); return;".

Try the following code:

```
'use strict';

var showComments = 0;
var counter = 10000;
var ab = process.argv[2];

function a(x, cb) {
    var myCB = function (err, result) { x = result; }

    x *= 1.01;
    if (showComments) console.log('start counter =', counter, ', x = ', x);

    if (--counter > 0) a(x, myCB);

    if (showComments) console.log("cb'ing");

    switch (ab) {
        case 'a':
            return cb(undefined, x);

        case 'b':
            cb(undefined, x);
            return;

        case 'c':
            process.nextTick(function () { cb(undefined, x); });
            return;

        default:
            console.log('Oops!  Try typing "node testReturnCallBack.js [a|b|c]"');
            process.exit(1);
    }
}

var start = (new Date()).getTime();

a(1, function (err, result) {
    console.log('final result = ', result);

    var finish = (new Date()).getTime();
    var diff = finish - start;
    console.log('run took %d milliseconds', diff);
});
```

And you should see that cases 'a' and 'b' run multiple times return basically the same time in milliseconds while the computed value remains constant.  Meanwhile case 'c' takes about 50% longer.