# returning or not callback, does it make a difference for node

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm just wondering if it make a difference to return the callback or not.

[It was already asked here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764943/javascript-difference-with-using-return-to-call-a-callbac) but not in the context of Node where virtually any IO function uses CPS. I didn't tag this question as Javascript because I believe it's irrelevant to the language, but more specific to how nodejs and v8 work internally.

So is there any difference (for V8) between these two version of the foo function

```
// foo that returns cb();
function foo(cb) {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 10, 10, function(err, bytesRead, buffer) {
        return cb(buffer);
    });
}

// foo that won't return cb()
function foo(cb) {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 10, 10, function(err, bytesRead, buffer) {
        cb(buffer);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In that case it doesn't because there is no code below the callback.  if you had code under the callback such as

```
// foo that won't return cb()
function foo(cb) {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 10, 10, function(err, bytesRead, buffer) {
        cb(buffer);
        console.log('yup')
    });
}
```

Then the code will continue to execute after the callback.  But if you add return the console will never execute

```
// foo that won't return cb()
function foo(cb) {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 10, 10, function(err, bytesRead, buffer) {
        return cb(buffer);
        //will never execute below
        console.log('yup')
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes obviously, thank you for the response. But it's not what I'm asking for :).

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking here.  You should check out the answer marked correct here.  It may shed a little light, though it's not a definitive answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843675/where-to-put-returns-around-callbacks-with-node-js

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, seems like I missed this question :). flagged as duplicate.